# One thread reading hashmap while other thread causing resizing

Tags: java, hashmap

I understand that HashMap is not thread safe and resizing is triggered from an update operation.

My question is what happens if there are two threads one performing get from HashMap and other thread performing put which results in resizing of hashMap.

What could be the possible output of get operation?

Comment: When you have unsynchronized thread access of shared memory, the results are undefined.  Anything could happen.  One author (Brian Goetz) says that unsynchronized operations "have no useful semantics."

Answer (score 4):

The result could be looping infinitely, not even returning a value but simply running forever.

It could also be that, but only on Tuesdays, and on other days it works perfectly normally.

The behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

From [the Javadoc of HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it *must* be synchronized externally.

In other words, the behavior described in the documentation only applies if you externally synchronize the access correctly.

If you do anything else, the behavior is undefined: it could literally do anything. Certain behaviors are more likely than others, for sure, but none of them are predictable or useful.

Answer (score 0):

In C lang specs, the result is literally undefined - the computer can blast some polka music from the speakers and that would still be fine.

In java, it's not like that, but it is **effectively** the same. The JMM (The Java Memory Model - see [section §17.4 of the JVM Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html)) can more or less accurately be simplified to the concept of an evil coin. Anytime any 2 threads interact with the same field **anywhere in the entire heap space**, unless they're all only reading and never writing, the JVM flips an evil coin. On heads, the threads share the variable, on tails, each thread gets a local copy that is synced back up at a random time in the future, possibly days ahead, perhaps never.

The coin is evil: At least if it was a fair-ish flip every time we just rerun a test a lot and eventually we'll cover every permutation of coin flips. But it's not - it's evil. Today it will flip such that all your tests pass and your application works perfectly. And it will tomorrow too. But 2 weeks from now just as that important customer comes in? Whoops.

The difference between C and java is that java at least *has* a coin, but in practice if you wrote your code such that it only works correctly if the coin lands the same way every time, it's a buggy mess. In many ways it's worse: An app that just straight up does the wrong thing at least is easily tested to confirm it's wrong.

In general here are the guarantees that the JVM offers:

- If there are 2 bytecode instructions (more or less, 2 lines of java code) that have an officially defined Happens-Before relationship (see section 17.4 that outlines how you establish that. `synchronized` is one way), then the JMM guarantees that the afterwards bytecode cannot observe any state as it was before the before-it line modified that state. If the after-it line doesn't try to observe any state, the JMM makes no guarantees that the 'before' line actually runs before. It only guarantees that you can't observe it. And it doesn't even guarantee that strictly: For example, any observation you do via timing (how long certain things take) aren't covered by the guarantee either.
- Theoretically, any operations on `long` and `double` can be observed in a sheared state, where the top 32 bits are in flight being updated but the bottom 32 bits haven't yet, or vice versa. In practice you won't be able to do that (you can't ever actually see shearing on 64-bit JVM impls on 64-bit hardware, and good luck finding some 32-bit hardware today). But a JVM is not broken if it shears longs or doubles, and if you were to report a bug to the OpenJDK project about such a thing it would be closed as 'specced and intended behaviour'.
- Other than that, the JVM guarantees atomic updates. Even for references if they happen to be processed as 64-bit. An atomic update means that if you have this code, and this is the only code that *ever* writes to this field: `private int x = 0; ... later on: x = -1;`, and you have other code running elsewhere (i.e. no Happens-Before established), then the other code is guaranteed to read either `0` or `-1`; the evil coin decides which one you get. But, if you get, say, `5`, then the JVM is buggy. For a `long` that doesn't theoretically hold due to the shearing thing. You might observe the top 32 bits being all zeroes and the bottom 32 bits being all ones (`-1` is, in bit terms, 64 one-bits), thus if you make that `private long x;` and a JVM ends up running such that a thread that runs `System.out.println(x)` ends up printing 4294967296, that's legal (thats 32 zero bits followed by 32 one bits): Due to shearing the top half is from the '0' value and the bottom half is the '-1' value.
- The JMM makes absolutely no guarantees whatsoever about ordering (outside of Happens-Before), and no guarantees about synchronization. In particular, an object that has become garbage can remain (un-garbage-collected) for days on end, and 2 threads each having a conflicting local copy may continue on with their local copy even if you can clearly tell the CPU has spent *hours* idling. The CPU isn't going to check for any 'work' to do if it doesn't have to. Or it does - evil coin decides.

### So, what about hashmap?

This is where we run into trouble. Any operations on fields themselves are at least atomic, so that means the university splits in twain anytime you do an unprotected read (one not guarded with a happens-before) - and thus you have to now consider '2 universes'. Which is doable. But 2 becomes 4, and 4 becomes 8 very very quickly. Because the JMM's guarantees about consistency are limited. If you somehow determine that the last out of 20 field reads **definitely** is a local cache value somehow, than you *cannot* conclude the previous 19 field reads must therefore also be local cache values. The JMM is free to flip the coin on every field. That means in theory your universe has now exploded into 2^20 = 1048576 distinct possibilities. In practice hardware limitations and OS implementations probably result in only 2 possibilities ever being even observable in the first place, but that's just today: The spec leaves the door open for some future where something else can happen, and, of course, CPU makers aren't sitting still either. Some behaviour that the spec says is theoretically possible but the JVM+ways CPU work today says it cannot possibly occur - might occur on as-yet-to-be-designed chips.

This is **why** folks like Brian Goetz say that while Java, unlike C, does lock down specifically which of a number of different ways contended situations can go - that's not **meaningfully** semantically useful.

Which gets us to your hashmap: The HashMap specification (the javadoc) would have to, more or less, duplicate **precisely** how the entire thing works, basically copy/paste every line of source code straight into the javadoc, if you want the spec to be able to tell you precisely what can happen for all permutations of every flip of the evil coin.

Which is silly - and isn't a thing HashMap has actually done. Therefore, HashMap **itself** has granted itself some leeway and spec-wise is allowed to act in ways that in practice cannot possibly occur **today** even if tomorrow with some point-update release of the JVM, all of a sudden it can occur.

Thus, even though at least at an individual field access level we can enumerate all possible things that the JMM spec dictates are possible - at the level of 'a bunch of code that acts as a consistent whole' such as `HashMap`, that has exploded into an unspecified universe that can be enumerated but contains so many options (millions) that there's no actual point.

That means **in practice** java is like C: If you break the rules and write code that violates the JMM (as in, does unsafe field reads), then you should act as if 'anything could happen, literally anything. Bugs that never happen except on the fifth monday of the third month when jupiter is ascending and the moon is in its seventh house and Bob Dylan is playing in the music player, oh, while the ambient temperature is above 30ºC - that kind of 'anything can happen'. Code that is buggy in a way that might be completely impossible to test for right now but which **will** show itself later, on a customer's computer.

To boil it down to the simplest conclusion: **Do not violate the JMM. Do not ever ship any code whose behaviour depends on any evil coin flip. Do not attempt to write code that is designed to avoid the cost of establishing HB by ending up doing the right thing regardless of flips because it's incredibly complicated and literally untestable. You will mess up, you won't know where or why, and you'll spend literally months bugchasing it. It isn't, ever, worth doing this**.

And thus, your question? It is unanswerable. Which is fine, because the answer is irrelevant. If you think it's worthwhile to know what could happen to figure out if some code is fine or not, the answer is already clear: No, the code is wrong, fix it.

Note that it's not just the resizing. If one thread puts something in the map while another thread also does so, even if no resizing is occurring, the hashmap may well completely break. And never in a nice way (that'd be that it starts throwing exceptions that tell you what happened). No, it'll just start answering wrong. Or you call `.get(someKey)` and the get method just hangs forever wasting 100% CPU. You **cannot** access the same hashmap from two threads unless you protect with HB (for example, if all such accesses are in `synchronized (thatMap) {}` you'd be fine).